# How do I exclude a global filter from testing in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter

I am working on an API which will have a 'before_filter :authorize_request' inside ApplicationController.

'authorize_request' method will do some request header validation with Signatures and HMAC validation.  However, I want to avoid calling this method before every single 'development or test' request because it means that I am going to have to mock eveerything and/or go through headaches trying to get tests to work.

Currently, I am hacking this be saying:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  before_filter :authorize_request
end
```

but that feels like a total hack.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `before_filter :authorize_request unless Rails.env.production?` would be the way I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also return early from the filter

```
def authorize_request
  return true if Rails.env.test?

  # carry on

end
```